# UK visa for Grandma

Tags: uk-visa

My married child and spouse, and my grandchildren, are moving to the UK for up to 5 years to work. I live with them. What type of visa will allow me to move with them?

Comment: What kind of visa is your spouse going to have? Your's would likely be the same unless you plan on residing in the UK on your own merit.

Comment: @ouflak I believe that refers to the spouse of Grandma's child

Comment: @user16259 -Ah yes, I took that to be the OP's spouse. Hmmm.... Unless the OP is completely financially dependent on her child, don't see a way.

Comment: Is your married child moving to the UK under EEA freedom of movement? If they are, then moving with them is a possibility. If not, it is extremely unlikely to be an option (and this would be true even if your child were a British citizen).

Comment: @dda I think 'their grandchildren' should read 'my grandchildren'

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this UK government website I don't think you'll be allowed to move with them unless they stay and settle in the UK. (Edit: but see @phoog comment below) Adult relatives can get a visa to join their adult children but only if the adult children are permanent residents of the UK. 5 years temporary work won't qualify. https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/adult-dependent-relative

Comment: If the adult child or spouse is an EEA citizen, the grandmother would likely qualify to join them through European Union freedom of movement.

Comment: If the grandmother is completely financially dependent on her child, it's possible via that route as well. Might need more info.